# How can I avoid using non null assertion (!!) in kotlin when I am dealing with Mono and Flux

Tags: kotlin, spring-webflux

How can I remove the !! operator when I have the following code?

```
val flux = Flux.just(Foo("Big"), Foo(null), Foo("Small"))
flux.filter { it.name != null }
    .map { functionThatRequiresAString(it.name!!) }


fun functionThatRequiresAString(name: String){
 // map
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a handy `mapNotNull` function, which you can use in conjunction with the safe call operator `?` to give:

```
flux.mapNotNull { it.name?.toUpperCase() }
```

This give the required output of BIG, SMALL

Comment: The Flux class does not have mapNotNull method, it is just for collections

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin offers quite a few lovely methods for dealing with nullable values. One that comes to my mind is `let`:

```
flux
  .filter { it.name != null }
  .map {it?.let { it1 -> it1.toUpperCase() }
```

Comment: It's identical to just writing `it.name?.toUpperCase()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine `filter` and `map` through [`flatMapIterable`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#flatMapIterable-java.util.function.Function-), using 0 elements when you need to skip something and 1 when you need to map it. Here

```
flux.flatMapIterable {
     val name = it.name
     if (name != null) listOf(functionThatRequiresAString(name)) else listOf()
}
```

RxJava has more specific `flatMapMaybe`, but Reactor doesn't seem to have an equivalent.